# Can class methods be added to some instances of Ruby objects but not others?

Tags: ruby, module, object-model

Here is a module containing some methods:

```
module M
  def x; y; end
  def y; ...; end
end
```

Here's a class:

```
class C
  def z; ...; end
end
```

I have two instances of `C`:

```
 c1 = C.new
 c2 = C.new
```

Is there something I can do to `c1` such that `c1.class` has `x` and `y`, but `c2.class` doesn't? I don't see a straightforward way to subvert the method lookup.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case?  Using class methods for instance-specific functionality seems like a generally bad idea.

Comment: @rcrogers: No kidding, but tell that to the Rails core developers. This is exactly how scopes work (and is the problem I'm trying to solve here, as I mentioned in a comment below).

Comment: @JohnFeminella Can you provide an example of your code using scopes in this way?

Comment: Calling a scope as an instance method?  Yeah, definitely need an example.  What about the scope makes it important that `c1` has it but `c2` doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override `c1.class` to return something other than C (and that other thing would extend M). Other than that, no.

Note that overriding `c1.class` is almost certainly a bad idea. An object shouldn't lie about what its class is.

Comment: I'm accepting this since it's the only one that actually answers the question ("no, it can't be done").

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing `c1.class.x`, why not do `c1.x`, as the [Law Of Demeter](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/) would suggest?

```
class C
  def self.x
    "hi"
  end
end

c1 = C.new
c2 = C.new
def c1.x
  self.class.x
end
c1.x # => "hi"
c2.x # NoMethodError
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the law of Demeter, but as I said, the methods I'm trying to add are class methods, not instance methods, and can't be transformed that way. (They are ActiveRecord scopes.) This is therefore not a valid solution.

Comment: @John thanks a lot for down voting me when your original question didn't bother explaining why this wouldn't be a valid solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that I've slighted you in some way, despite the unwarranted assumptions about who's downvoting you. But I think I was pretty clear that these are methods on the class, not methods on the object. (I said it twice in the question, and there's a code snippet to illustrate an example.) If you think it could be clearer, you're certainly welcome to edit it.

Comment: @JohnFeminella "I'm sorry if you feel that I've slighted you in some way" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-apology_apology

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
c1.extend(M)

c1.methods & [:x, :y] #=> [:x, :y]
c2.methods & [:x, :y] #=> []
```

Comment: That doesn't affect the methods that `c1.class` and `c2.class` have though.

Comment: I didn't see any connection between c1.class and module M, I just made a guess.

Comment: The OP wants M's methods on c1.class, so that he can call `c1.class.x()` and `c1.class.y()`, but not `c2.class.x()` or `c2.class.y()`. Your code does not achieve that.

Comment: Strange, c1.class and c2.class are the same object(or class), what OP really wants?